# In google benchmark, what is the meaning of Iterms_per_seconds and Why we need fixture?

Tags: c++, benchmarking, google-benchmark

In google benchmark:
there is a Iterms_per_seconds result and we can use the fixture way to test the bench.

[image]

[image]

1. What is the meaning of Iterms_per_seconds in google bench? Is it stands the throuput?
2. Why need the fixture to test benchmark? In this way , can we get more convenience?

Comment: Please, send textual info (specifically source code) as text. You may also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: In your screenshot, it says "items/s", not "iterms/s". But are you sure that's not itself a typo for `iters/s`, iterations?  I guess probably not; your numbers "iterations" and "time" numbers don't match that.

Comment: Also, you don't need fixtures, you can just benchmark a function if you want, like in [What is the meaning of Google Benchmark Iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58493236) if that's more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. items per second is the throughput. items is defined by the benchmark author and is completely optional. the benchmark author can also define bytes processed for bytes per second, if that is more meaningful.
2. you don't need fixtures, but they provide a way to do one-off setup and teardown.